# How to fetch 20 item each time when reach the end of RecyclerView,and the make sure it different from the previous item?

Tags: php, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which I want it to be endless scroll,so whenever I reach the last 5 item,it make request to server again.This part so far no problem,it can detect the last 5 item in RecyclerView and make Volley request again.

The main problem now is,the data that request at the 2nd time(request that made when reach the last 5 item) is the same data from the 1st time.

Therefore,what I want is,at the 1st request(user just launch the activity)request fetch 20 posts and display it,when reach the last 5 item,request 20 posts again which is different with the 1st 20posts.

**So far what I tried is**

**Set a offset**

```
// initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
 private int offSet = 0;
```

**Update the offset with the Id that fetch at 1st request**

```
// updating offset value to highest value
  if (id >= offSet)
      offSet = id;
```

**Send the `offset` value to the php server in volley(The same volley request of the 1st request)**

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
// Posting params to  endpoint                          
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("offset", String.valueOf(offSet));

 return params;
}
```

**So in my php code I handle like this**

```
    $offsetString =$app->request()->get('offset');
    $offset =(int) $offsetString;
    $limit=20;
    //loop though result and get the 20 post each time
    for ($j = $offset; $j < $offset + $limit && $j < sizeof($item = $result->fetch_assoc()); $j++) {           

            $tmp = array();
            $tmp['post_id'] = $item['item_id'][$j];
            $tmp['username'] = $item['username'][$j];
            $tmp['profile_image_path'] = $item['profile_image_path'][$j];
            $tmp['status_body'] = $item['status_body'][$j];
            $tmp['image_path'] = $item['image_path'][$j];
            $tmp['post_created_at'] = $item['created_at'][$j];
            array_push($response['item'], $tmp);
  }
```

**But end up my Json become like this which is weird,and totally different JSON with my Json before.**

```
 {"feed":[{"item_id":null,"username":"k","profile_image_path":"h","status_body":"I","image_path":"h","created_at":"2"},{"item_id":null,"username":"e","profile_image_path":"t","status_body":"h","image_path":"t","created_at":"0"},
```

**At this moment,once reach last 5 item in RecyclerView,I use the same function to make request.Which is look like this:**

```
//for endless scroll
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // End has been reached

                Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");

                //This is Volley request to fetch data from Server
                //should I make another volley request that different with the 1st request
                fetchPost(); 

                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

So,I need to know what I miss out,or the correct way to solve this problem?

The most importantly,what should I do in php part?

Or should I make a 2 separate Volley Request to fetch data?

Comment: This is probably happening because there are two calls getting hit at same OR offset value is not being properly set. Check logs for this two things

Comment: check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtVHvifaKC4&t=3s youtube video. jump to 13:40 minutes and watch you will get how to load data on scrolling.

Comment: @AdnanMomin cause I using volley,therefore in the video is using OKHTTP,therefore I not sure how to pass the id to my php script.Can u help?

Comment: @ken I haven't used volley. I don't know how it works. Try to implement logic shown in video

Comment: @AdnanMomin ok thanks,I tried it,it help me alot..

Comment: @ken so please vote me

Comment: @AdnanMomin please answer my question,so i can vote u